# Нахождение методов в памяти

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Есть переменные (объекты) которые могут храниться как в куче так и в стеке. Есть реализации методов у какого-то класса. (Речь не будет идти о виртуальных методах и VTable)

Где хранятся реализации методов в памяти, если они там хранятся? И как программа знает как (или по какому адресу) выполнять эти методы?

Comment: [Where are methods stored in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298122/where-are-methods-stored-in-memory)

Comment: Да, спасибо) Но это не полностью дает ответ на мой вопрос)

Comment: поэтому я запостил это комментарием, а не ответом :)

Comment: Прости, я просто здесь новый и не понимаю здешних правил) Да, моя вина в том что не прочитал правила (Если они тут есть)
То что, в момент, когда JIT преобразует IL (или MSIL) в двоичный код, методы помещаются в какой-то участок памяти, это я уже читал. Мне интересно знать куда именно помещается метод. Куда заносится адрес, по которому можно вызвать метод.

Comment: никаких проблем. Если есть желание почитать правила, можно начать [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

В .NET реализация методов находится в памяти в 2 экземплярах: MSIL-коде, и в машинном коде. При компиляции MSIL-кода JIT создает в памяти функции на машинном коде. При этом JIT знает соответствия между .NET методами, и адресами функций на машинном коде. В итоге при генерации машинного кода JIT просто подставляет адреса этих функций. Они не будут меняться (перемещаться в памяти), так что волноваться не о чем.

Пример. C# код:

```
Console.ReadKey();
Console.ReadKey();
Console.ReadKey();
Debugger.Break();
```

Сгенерированный машинный код:

```
lea         rcx,[rsp+48h]  
xor         edx,edx  
call        000007FEF1820C00  // Console.ReadKey
lea         rcx,[rsp+38h]  
xor         edx,edx  
call        000007FEF1820C00  // Console.ReadKey
lea         rcx,[rsp+28h]  
xor         edx,edx  
call        000007FEF1820C00  // Console.ReadKey
call        000007FEF181E870  // Debugger.Break
```

Как видно, в рантайме никто не ищет методы, иначе все бы работало намного медленнее.

CLR держит в памяти структуры, называемыми `Method Table Structure`. Для каждого класса и каждого метода CLR помнит, есть ли скомпилированная в машинный код версия метода, и если есть, то где находится ее адрес.

Для каждого типа CLR создает структуру, которая описывает его. В этой структуре находится таблица методов (включая информацию по виртуальным методам). Все эти CLR-структуры находятся в отдельной области памяти, которой управляет CLR. Область памяти с экземплярами .NET-классов (`Managed Heap`) находиться отдельно, и она управляется сборщиком мусора.

Comment: а как насчет виртуальных методов? Будет ли происходить поиск нужного метода, если виртуальный метод был перегружен или обычный метод был скрыт? Я где то читал давно-давно, что вызов метода структуры быстрее именно из за того, что он не может быть перекрыт наследниками, то есть какой то (может и небольшой) но есть оверхед при вызове функции класса - хотя я давно читал и, может, неверно помню инфу.

Comment: Method Table Structure у каждого класса свой и находится в куче, там где и сам класс?

Comment: @tym32167 это уже другой вопрос :) насколько я знаю, там есть 2 разных MSIL команды `call` и `callvirt`, соответственно по ним JIT генерирует разный код

Comment: да да, я как раз про `callvirt`. Ну, другой так другой :)

Comment: По поводу виртуальных методов, то у каждого класса есть VTable (Таблица виртуальных методов). Она содержит адреса на реализации методов. Если класс B, наследуется от A, и оверайдит реализацию метода C, тогда в VTable класса A, ссылка на метод C будет ссылаться на перезаписанную реализацию этого метода. Как то так)

Comment: @VitalyEvtukh Да, в каждого класса своя таблица методов. Она не совсем в той куче, которую принято называть кучей в .NET. Это отдельная область памяти, которая управляется только CLR. Куча, где содержатся экземпляры .NET объектов управляется сборщиком мусора.

Comment: Ага, было бы забавно, если бы GC удалил не используемый явно кодом тип :)

Comment: @Zergatul Значит у CLR есть своя куча, в которой находятся классы (Не экземпляры классов), и у каждого класса есть Method Table.И эта куча находится в области памяти, выделенной под CLR. А экземпляры классов находятся в Managed Heap, и в экземплярах классов находятся VTable. Я все правильно понимаю?

Comment: @VitalyEvtukh Да, правильно. Только экземпляры не содержат указателя на VTable. У них есть указатель на структуру в CLR, которая описывает тип (например, через этот указатель работает метод `object.GetType()`). А в этой структуре уже содержится инфа о всех методах (включая виртуальные).

Answer (score 2):

> как программа знает как (или по какому адресу) выполнять эти методы?

Каждая программа работает с памятью не напрямую с физической, а с виртуальной памятью, думая, что она владеет полностью всей памяти и никто(другой процесс) не может ей мешать, хотя по факту часть программы может вообще находится не в ОЗУ, а быть выгруженной на диск, но для программы это прозрачно и она видит непрерывное адресное пространство.

Как следствие, компилятор на стадии компиляции может указать, что такой то метод находится по такому-то адресу, а такой то по такому не вычисляя ничего в рантайме.

Далее ОС используя виртуальные таблицы преобразует виртуальную память в физическую и обращается к физическим ячейкам.

Рихетр "Операционные системы"